# Get ImageView without knowing about it

Tags: android

I have custom Dialog that show 4 ImageViews (All Photos, Favorites, Taged, Albums).

The layout is something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
<ImageView>...1</ImageView>
<ImageView>...2</ImageView>
<ImageView>...3</ImageView>
<ImageView>...4</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The constructor contains this code:

```
iv = new ImageView[3];
iv[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoAll);
iv[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoFavorites);
iv[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoTags);
iv[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoAlbums);

for (ImageView image : iv){
            image.setOnClickListener(new DialogPhotoOnItemClickListener(context, image));
        }
```

The listener is:

```
package com.kappa.cloudgallery.listeners;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kappa.cloudgallery.R;
import com.kappa.cloudgallery.widgets.DialogPhoto;

public class DialogPhotoOnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    Context context;
    ImageView iv;

    public DialogPhotoOnItemClickListener(Context context, ImageView imageView){
        this.context = context;
        this.iv = imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (iv.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnPhotoAll:
                Toast.makeText(context, "All", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPhotoFavorites:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPhotoTags:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Tags", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPhotoAlbums:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Albums", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is that i pass the imageview in constructor. There is any efficient way to get which image i clicked?**

Dialog: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kcii.png)

Comment: Pass the id instead?

Comment: Yea! but it would be same. The idea is to pass nothing and find it using `View view` on `onClick` event. If there is any idea!

Comment: Well, you have to have some reference to an id, otherwise you cannot compare the clicked view's id to anything

Comment: This code doesn't make sense other then academic reasons ... what you wana achive? to show toast? `<ImageView android:tag="All" >...` then in onClick `Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getTag(),...)` ... seriously ... what is the point

Comment: It is Photo Gallery App. Each of these options filter photos. The first one show all photos. The second show only favorite photos etc. So... it is Custom `Dialog`.

Comment: http://s12.postimg.org/m02qfqxlp/Screenshot_2015_10_20_15_28_57.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
  switch (iv.getId()){
  }
}
```

You are using `iv.getId()` instead of this use `view.getId()`. And you don't need to pass Imageview in constructor.

Comment: good finding ... I was wonder why he is passing imageview at all ... and when I was reading, my brain translated `iv.getId()` into `view.getId()` as `iv.getId()` is bizarre

Comment: Ty. some things are too obvious... sh1t :P

Comment: @GeorgeJ plz accpet answer if it's useful